# Windows implementation of Mac Spaces

Tags: windows, macos, desktop

I've just listened to episode 6 of StackOverflow podcast, and I just wonder, is there a free and good enough implementation of Mac Spaces for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a Virtual Desktop Manager [PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx).  Not nearly as good as the ones on Linux & OSX, though.

Answer (score 3):

try [Dexpo](http://www.dexpot.de)

from their website

> With Dexpot you may have separate virtual desktops for different applications. One desktop might feature applications for graphic design, for example, and another might feature your business applications.
>
> Switch between virtual desktops in order to keep track of your open windows. Using Dexpot, you'll considerably increase your workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try the **[Microsoft Sysinternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881)**, it offers 4 virtual desktops.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, at least not for XP.  It's hard because xp wasn't designed with that in mind, while Mac and Linux handle it beautifully.

The best one for XP that I have found is [VirtualWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/), which just works by hiding windows.  It's hacky, but at least it gets the main idea down.  I think if you've got an accelerated desktop like vista, [VDM](http://www.codeplex.com/vdm) might be worth a look.  But since I don't have vista, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Dexpot is the best i've found for options and functionality, however the free version comes with some trashware in the installer, if you just install the pro trial and then tear down the free version installer with 7zip and copy the program files in to the program directory - it works like a champ however - No trashware.

Try not to break your computer doing this.